# pronunciation of 'ctl' in commands like 'systemctl'

Tags: unix, unix-utils, systemctl

There are sorts of commands like 'systemctl', 'hostnamectl', or 'jounralctl'. I realize that 'ctl' is shorthand for control, but I'm wondering what the generally accepted pronunciation of 'ctl' is.

Comment: see-tee-ell. As in hostname-see-tee-ell.

Comment: I'm disappointed to see this question closed. Rather than "debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion", there will be one, or maybe two valid answers. This similar question (for zsh) is quite useful: http://superuser.com/questions/178174/how-is-zsh-pronounced

Comment: `cuddle`, `control`, and `c-t-l` seem to be what I hear the most.